# Требуется найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c++

Программа компилируется, но при запуске и вводе первого значения вылетает ошибка. В чем проблема понять не могу.
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    int n;
    string s;
    string temp;
    int numb;
    int mass[97];

    for(int i = 0; i < 98; i++)
    {

        mass[i] = 0;

    }

    cin >> n;

        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {


        getline(cin, s);
        if(s.substr(s.length()-2, 1) == " ")
        {
            temp = s.substr(s.length()-1, 1);
            numb = atoi(temp.c_str());
            mass[numb - 1] = mass[numb - 1] + 1;


        }
        else
        {
            temp = s.substr(s.length()-1, 1);
            numb = atoi(temp.c_str());
            mass[numb - 1] = mass[numb - 1] + 1;


        }
        }


    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++)
    {
        if(mass[u] > 0)
        {

            cout << "School №" << u << ": " << mass[u] << endl; 

        }


    }




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

не будем даже далеко ходить...

```
int mass[97];
```

Массив из 97 элементов.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 98; i++)
{
    mass[i] = 0;
}
```

Записываются элементы 0, 1, 2, ..., 97 - итого 98 штук. Уже UB.

Далее - `cin >> n;`. В буфере остается `'\n'`.

```
getline(cin, s);
```

Считывается пустая строка.

```
if(s.substr(s.length()-2, 1) == " ")
```

И идет попытка откуда-то до ее начала подстроку получить...

Дальше даже не смотрел.